# Undefined method `request_uri' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to follow a tutorial online to set up an authentication system using LDAP active directory (have a VERY tough time). So the current error is:

```
undefined method `request_uri' for nil:NilClass
```

Referring to the following in my application controller:

```
def authenticate
unless session[:person]
session[:return_to] = @request.request_uri
redirect_to :controller => "login" , :action => "index"
return false
```

That part, I think, is supposed to save the url in an @request instance so that it can redirect the user there once he is logged in.

Is `request_uri` the wrong method? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the method being called.  If you notice the error, the problem is you're calling a method on nil.  In other words, @request does not exist.

When accessing the request variable, it's literally **request**, not @request.

Comment: Yeah just realized that, and i discovered, that in rails 3 it isnt request_uri, its fullpath, now its working.. thanks for your help! I opened a new question i need help with if you dont mind.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041561/ldap-authentication-always-returning-true