# LDAP authentication always returning true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im following a tutorial online (http://my.opera.com/learnror/blog/ldap-binding-and-authentication-ror) to setup authentication against an LDAp active directory (have a pretty tough time with it too). Anyway, i got the login form and everything setup but for some reason, no matter what i type into the form, (even wrong/nonexistent credentials), it comes back as true! Can anyone help?

OR can anyone provide away to have some sort of debugger run the code line by line (like done with jaavscript debugger). Heres the code that authenticates the login form: (the LDAP module is in a separate lib file):

```
def authenticate
if session[:person] = LDAP.authenticate(params[:login][:name], params[:login][:p
assword])
session[:username] = params[:login][:name]

if session[:return_to]
redirect_to(session[:return_to])
session[:return_to] = nil
else
redirect_to :controller => 'login' , :action => 'index'
end
else
flash[:notice] = "Login failed!"
redirect_to :action => "index"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you used = instead of == in if session[:person] = LDAP…  == means equals, = means assignment.

Comment: That did it! Now when i type anything in (even credentials that should be working) it simply redirects to the login form), so the problem must be that i have improperly configured the LDAP module, correct?

Comment: Yes, it would be best to look through the API documentation for the LDAP library that you're using.  See the section where it says (on that URL you sent), "I didn’t want to use a full-blown ActiveLdap implementation so I decided to customize the plugin generated code of the restful_authentication plugin.
The application is still on Rails 1.2.3 and it uses an older version of restful_authentication. So if you’re going to try this yourself, there might be some differences with the code snippets below… but I’m sure you’ll figure it out."  Rails 1.2.3 is very, very old, I would look for a new gem.

Comment: Github.com is the best place (imo) to search for gems, just type in rails ldap gem and look for something that is compatible with the version of Rails that you're running.

Comment: Where did you see that paragraph on the link i sent you? I didnt see that.. regardless, i only need to replace the net ldap gem, correct? Because that one isnt compatible on rails 3?

Comment: My fault, I had several links open and must have picked from the wrong one.  Sorry about that.  I would definitely look for a Rails3 compatible gem, as Rails3 had a lot of changes.

Comment: Ok no problem, anyways i think the one in the tutorial im following also isnt rails 3 compatible bc the tutorial is 2009. So hopefully, ill udpate the ldap for rails and all will be well. (ive been working on this for two days so cross your fingers!)

Comment: This might help: http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/readme/devise_with_ldap_for_authentication_in_rails_3

Comment: That looks perfect!! Im going to start over using that

Comment: Trying to get this tutorial's method working! Opened a new question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044013/devise-authentication-undefined-method-to-sym