# Devise authentication undefined method 'to_sym'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im trying to set up an authentication system against an LDAP active directory using devise. (following the tutorial http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/readme/devise_with_ldap_for_authentication_in_rails_3

Ive followed the instruction exactly, and when i try running the app im getting the following error:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for #<ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::WhiteList:0x2a4abd50
```

And i dont even know where `to_sym` is because it doesnt tell me! Anyone know the cause of this or at least how to find the file that contains this line?
******************UPDATE******************

user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
and :omniauthable
  devise :ldap_authenticatable,
       :rememberable, :trackable,

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible(:login, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me)
end
```

Comment: to_sym is a method that will convert the value into a ruby symbol (<some-object> ---> :some-object. without seeing code and such I don't know exactly what's going on. I've never tried to use ldap w/devise.

Comment: @jaydel Exactly. The error doesnt say where to_sym is located. Do you know of any debugging methods to get a more detailed error?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Have you tried the ruby debugger? Also, I've encountered similar things like this in other ways...for example missing method 'gsub' or 'match' on some things and in those cases it turned out that I was defining something as a class rather than a string in an association....for example :class_name => FooObject rather than :class_name => "FooObject". you might check out places where you're configuring "special circumstances" with these sorts of hash values...

Comment: Devise injects a call to `attr_accessible` in your user model. This creates a whitelist of attributes which can be assigned values through the `params` hash (this sounds related to the error you're getting). If you posted your model, specifically the call to `devise`, it would probably help us debug this.

Comment: @Danny Ok i updated my question with the user.rb model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a trailing comma after the last argument to the `devise` method:

```
devise :ldap_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable,
```

The ruby interpreter then assumes that `attr_accessible` is the next argument to the method. The proper argument type is a symbol, so it calls `to_sym` on `attr_accessible`, which is a method and does not have a `to_sym` method and raises the error.

Remove the trailing comma and it should work!

Comment: Net::LDAP::LdapError (no connection to server):

Comment: Yep, you need to start an ldap server. I have no experience with this, but I saw it done in this video: http://random-rails.blogspot.com/2010/07/ldap-authentication-with-devise.html